# Publish a single package from a project as maven artifact

Tags: java, maven, model, microservices, artifact

I'm working on a microservices system composed of many APIs written in Java (spring boot), I'm facing some instances wherein a microservice I have to use models defined in another one (e.g. when an API-to-API request is made and the results need to be parsed into an object). The models are usually defined in a 'models' package and do not depend on other packages. I don't really like the idea to copy/paste from a project to another, as it is error-prone and easily introduces a lot of overhead (e.g. when a model needs to be edited). I was wondering if there is a way, maybe with a maven configuration, to extract only the model package in a separate jar, and then publish it as a maven artifact (we have an internal repository). This would allow us to freely use models classes belonging to a project into another, without worrying about maintaining updated two definitions of the same model. It'd also be much better than having the models as a completely separate project.

Comment: You can configure with Maven modules, use `mvn deploy`, and a configure plugin `execution` to ignore the deployment for some modules.

Answer (score 1):

Well it's better to extract whole module instead of package, just add it in pom.xml.

I don't know if I understood you correctly -
Let's consider the situation:
You have Project A where you have get endpoint, lets say you have class User.
This class should be "shared", so let's put it in module ProjectA-API. You define API packaging as jar, and you add it in dependencies in ProjectA-War module. And as well you are adding it to pom in ProjectB-War, and then you can use the same model class for User both in caller's and calling site.

Is it helpful or you meant something different?

Small diagram for visualizing - [image]

Answer (score 0):

No.

The solution is to have the models a separate project.

Alternatively, you can construct multi-module-projects, so that building many artifacts is less of a hassle.